# LoadRunner Correlation : how to correlate dynamic values generating in array and each array value is having some common fields

Tags: arrays, dynamic, correlation, loadrunner

In my script there is array of array. Please help me how to correlate this . in below, during recording I have searched a particular site(iput data) that is 'ObservingSiteId'. for each specific 'ObservingSiteId' there will be more than one siteIDs will be fetched in array which is 'ObservedSites[n]' here and for every 'ObservedSites' there will be few common fields like 'minFromDate' , 'LastObserved' etc.
So in my script if I want to make it dynamic and parameterize 'ObservingSiteId' then how to capture rest of the things for each data.

```
            "Name=__RequestVerificationToken", "Value=<some value>", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SelectedObservingSiteId", "Value=abc", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservingSiteId", "Value=abc", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SelectedObservingSiteDisplayId", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[0].Id", "Value=xyz", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[0].MinFromDate", "Value=1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[0].LastObserved", "Value=2/8/2023 2:45:00 PM", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[0].TimeZoneOffset", "Value=124", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[0].WhenObservedDate", "Value=2/8/2023", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[0].WhenObservedTime", "Value=04:46 PM", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[0].TempClosed", "Value=false", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[0].ObservedPrices[0].Key", "Value=16", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[0].ObservedPrices[0].Value.Price", "Value=137.6", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[0].ObservedPrices[0].Value.CurrentMinValue", "Value=0.000", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[0].ObservedPrices[0].Value.CurrentMaxValue", "Value=9999.000", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[0].WasObserved", "Value=true", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[0].WasObserved", "Value=false", ENDITEM, 
            "Name=ObservedSites[1].Id", "Value=def", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[1].MinFromDate", "Value=1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[1].LastObserved", "Value=2/8/2023 2:45:00 PM", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[1].TimeZoneOffset", "Value=124", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[1].WhenObservedDate", "Value=2/8/2023", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[1].WhenObservedTime", "Value=04:46 PM", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[1].TempClosed", "Value=false", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[1].ObservedPrices[0].Key", "Value=16", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[1].ObservedPrices[0].Value.Price", "Value=137.6", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[1].ObservedPrices[0].Value.CurrentMinValue", "Value=0.000", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[1].ObservedPrices[0].Value.CurrentMaxValue", "Value=9999.000", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[1].WasObserved", "Value=true", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ObservedSites[1].WasObserved", "Value=false", ENDITEM,
```

The request verification token I have correlated. No issue on that and parameterize the 'ObservingSiteId'. But not able to figure out how to capture the array values.

Answer (score 0):

See web_custom_request() for variable length responses

See your training material for correlation candidate identification methods.

Engage your assigned mentor for assistance in handling this complex case involving multiple asset correlation, variable length responses and custom string generation.